# How can I change the binding of the property Text with the EvenTrigger "GotFocus"

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a TextBox in WPF/XAML.
I want to change the binding of the property Text with the event "GotFocus".

1. TextBox has no focus (simplified code):
   <TextBox Text="{Binding ShortValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
2. TextBox has focus:
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"

Changing the binding of the property Text is to be created with XAML.

So far I have the following:

```
<TextBox>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
           <!-- I'm at a loss here -->
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no behavior in the `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` package that lets you change the binding in pure XAML.

You could handle the event(s), either in the code-behind the view or in an attached behaviour, and create a new binding `programmatically`:

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
    ((TextBox)sender).SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("Value"));

private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
    ((TextBox)sender).SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("ShortValue"));
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding ShortValue}"
    GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"
    LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Xaml-only solution

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ShortValue}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Value}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style> 
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Notice that you have to set the default binding (i.e ShortValue) inside the style..

Comment: Nice one. Or aswell with `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">` and same setters

Comment: @lidqy `EventTrigger ` does not accept the same setters, it takes a collection of `TriggerAction`s only.